How to clone a div with dynamic values
i have a set of li that dynamically adding to page with jQuery draggable
every things work fine, now i added duplicate icon and onclick have clone my div:
   $(document).on('click', '.copy-question', function() {
                var newId = 123;
                var element = $(this).closest('li.FormItem');
                var newElement = element.clone();
                element.after(newElement);
    });

li content is:
<li class="FormItem text-field" data-id="sorting" data-me="1722453902890" type="text">
    <div class="field-actions">
        <a type="edit" class="toggle-form btn formbuilder-icon-pencil copy-question" data-id="1722453902890"
            title="duplicate">duplicate</a>
        <a type="remove" class="del-button btn formbuilder-icon-cancel delete-question" title="x">X</a>
    </div>
    <label class="field-label handle toplabel">(سورتینگ)</label>
    <span class="tooltip-element" style="display: none">?</span>
    <div class="frm-holder">
        <div class="form-elements">
            <input type="hidden" name="question[1722453902890][Qtype]" value="sorting" />
            <div class="form-group placeholder-wrap" style="display: block">
                <label>title</label>
                <div class="input-wrap">
                    <input name="question[1722453902890][label]" class="fld-label form-control" value="title"
                        type="text" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group name-wrap" style="display: block">
                <label>options</label>
                <div class="input-wrap">
                    <div class="sortable-options-wrap" style="height: auto">
                        <ol class="sortable-options">
                            <li class="ui-sortable-handle">
                                <input value="11" type="text" name="question[1722453902890][option][]" data-attr="label"
                                    class="option-label option-attr" />
                            </li>
                            <li class="ui-sortable-handle">
                                <input value="22" type="text" name="question[1722453902890][option][]" data-attr="label"
                                    class="option-label option-attr" />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <input value="33" type="text" data-attr="label" name="question[1722453902890][option][]"
                                    class="option-label option-attr" />
                                <a class="remove btn remove-option" style="right: unset; width: unset">X</a>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                        <div class="option-actions">
                            <a data-count="1722453902890" class="add add-opt">+ </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="close-field d-none">بستن</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>

this li have some input that can dynamically add or remove and a filed with title
when i clone this, new values not clone to new element
and cloned element have old values of inputs
how can duplicate this li with all current dynamic rows and values? (like google form)
thanks all
i tried to get element with
   var element = document.getElementById('id'+oldId);
    var element = $(document).find('#id' + oldId);
    var element = document.querySelector('#id' + oldId);
    var element = $(document.getElementById('#id' + oldId));
    var newElemnt = $(this).closest('li.FormItem').clone(true,true); 
    var newElemnt =  $(this).closest('li.FormItem')[0].outerHTML;
    var str = $(this).closest('li.FormItem').clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
    //console.log(newElemnt.prop('outerHTML'));
    console.log(element.outerHTML());
    console.log(newElemnt.prop('innerHTML'));
    //console.log(element.prop('outerHTML'));
    //console.log(element.prop('innerHTML'));
    //console.log($(this).closest('li.FormItem').html());
    // console.log(oldId);

but all of then return old values (fresh li)
and can not get new value of elements
update:
i use this code to get old elements and loop on it, then change value of clone
        parent = $(this).parent().parent();
        old_values = parent.find('[name*="' + id + '"]');
        var $clone = $(this).parent().parent().clone(true);
        old_values.each(function (key, value) {
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var value = $(this).val();
            $clone.find('[name*="' + id + '"]').eq(key).val(value);
        })
        console.log($clone.html());

but $clone.html() return old elements and $clone.find('[name*="' + id + '"]').eq(key).val(value); not working

Changes the user makes to input field values are not reflected in the DOM. You need to loop over the fields in your "original", get their current value, and then assign that to the corresponding fields in your clone.

@CBroe Ok, so how can i loop to all original elements (contain every tags like hidden img label and …) for assign to clone element?

Select all relevant elements in your original, and the exact same elements in your clone. Then loop over the former collection, and use the loop index to access the corresponding element with the second. Depending on the element type, you will either have to set the value, or the checked/selected status.

@CBroe loop code is added in question,  but changing clone values not working and clone didnt updated

This lacks context right now, I don't know where you put that, or even what id is supposed to be.

Short example here, that currently only takes care of text-type input fields: https://jsfiddle.net/jzfn9rox/ If you need it to work for checkboxes, radio buttons, select fields and textareas as well, you'll have to add the necessary logic.

"but $clone.html() return old elements" - setting the value property via JavaScript, also doesn't change the actual attribute. But if you insert the clone into the document first, and manipulate the values afterwards, that should not matter much. Unless you had a reset button for your form somewhere, that resets all fields to their defaults. If you wanted to handle that case correctly as well, then you would need to not manipulate the value property, but the actual attribute.
